How do I work out what is using the bandwidth on my site?
Please forgive me if this is a basic question, but I have searched around and haven't found an answer yet.
I am a developer on a web site that is hosted on a Ubuntu server. I do not have full access to the server, I can only use the control panel (Plesk) that I have been given.
Looking at the stats from the control panel, I can see that the HTTP bandwidth for the site is about 6Gb per month, which seems excessive, given the nature of the site (password-protected admin site) and the modest number of users . However, I can't see a way to work out how that breaks down. In order to try and reduce the bandwidth, I'd need to know which pages, resources, etc are taking up the bandwidth.
Please note that I do not have permission to install anything on the server, so can only use any built-in resources.
Anyone any suggestions? Thanks

"so can only use any built-in resources."  the tools you need you also need admin permissions. best course of action: ask the admin. apache/nginx logs  are in /var/logs/.

@Rinzwind Pardon my ignorance, but I'm not (yet) a Linux expert. Would those logs show individual requests, so I can parse them and see which take up the bandwidth? I currently have access to /var/log/passenger/passenger.log, but that seems to be a dump for all application output rather than a log of HTTP requests

/var/log/{apache,nginx}/ has all access requests. not sure if you can see what you need there but that log generally requires admin permissions to go into the directory.

@Rinzwind's suggestion to look at the log files is probably the best you can do. For every request, Apache (if that is what you are running) logs the byte count of the output. You would need a script to scrape this number from each line, and add them all up. That would still not be complete because it misses the overhead from HTTP headers, and probably the website will initiate some internet traffic itself. But it is a start.

@Rinzwind OK, thanks, I'll ask the sys admin for permissions.

@Jos I've done similar things with IIS logs, so am not worried about writing a script. As for the extra weight from headers, yeah it will make some difference, but given the large bandwidth usage I saw, I suspect there is something big enough in there that will render the header part irrelevant!
